# Powershell Get-ChildItem -recurse doesn't get all items

Tags: powershell, recursion, delete-file, subdirectory, get-childitem

I'm working on a powershell script erase certain files from a folder, and move the rest into predefined subfolders.

My structure looks like this

```
Main
    (Contains a bunch of pdb and dll files)
    -- _publish
        --Website
            (Contains a web.config, two other .config files and a global.asax file)
            -- bin
                (Contains a pdb and dll file)
            -- JS
            -- Pages
            -- Resources
```

I want to remove all pdb, config and asax files from the entire file structure before I start moving them. To which I use:

```
$pdbfiles = Get-ChildItem "$executingScriptDirectory\*.pdb" -recurse

foreach ($file in $pdbfiles) {
    Remove-Item $file
}
```

And so on for all filetypes I need removed. It works great except for a pdb file located in the bin folder of the website. And for the ASAX file in the website folder. For some reason they get ignored by the Get-ChildItem recurse search.

Is this caused by the depth of the items within the resursive structure? Or is it something else? How can I fix it, so it removes ALL files as specified.

**EDIT: I have tried adding -force - But it changed nothing**

**ANSWER: The following worked:**

```
$include = @("*.asax","*.pdb","*.config")
$removefiles = Get-ChildItem "$executingScriptDirectory\*" -recurse -force -include $include 

foreach ($file in $removefiles) {
    if ($file.Name -ne "Web.config") {
        Remove-Item $file
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you tried with `Get-ChildItem -force`?

Comment: I know I'm late to the party.  The script above works in PowerShell v3 and up.  I ran into this problem when I found out that the production server only had PowerShell v2.  You can check by dumping the `$PSVersionTable` variable

Answer (score 21, accepted):

```
Get-ChildItem -path <yourpath> -recurse -Include *.pdb
```

Comment: Yes I just found out as I updated this and read it. Thank you very much.

Comment: You can specify several extensions in the include part, separating them with a coma: gci -path <yourpath> -recurse -Include *.pdb, *.asax

Comment: Thank you very much for all your help - Updated the question with my solution.

Comment: @Xenoxsis note - if only one filter is needed use `-filter` instead of `-include` because its much faster. You will really notice the difference with large directory structures.

Answer (score 2):

You can also use the pipe for remove:

```
Get-ChildItem -path <yourpath> -recurse -Include *.pdb | rm
```